# how do i select one option from input list using DOM api

Tags: javascript, dom

```
 <input list="genderList" id="genderListId">
 <datalist id="genderList">
    <option value="MALE"></option>
    <option value="FEMALE"></option>
 </datalist>
```

In the above example, how to set the value to one of the available options.

when using below code, `MALE` text is displayed in UI, but value is still not updated

```
document.querySelector('#genderListId').value = 'MALE'
```

Comment: What do you mean by _value is still not updated_? I could see the value in the textbox, and could get the value using `document.querySelector('#genderListId').value` in `console.log` statement.

Comment: It works for me also - I posted an answer with your code in a snippet - but deleted the post cos it works as expected. - What about it does not work as you expect?

Comment: ui is updated and i can see the value in text box, but when i click the submit button in a form(which i did not show) value in input is still empty.
Adding more context: It is react application, but i am trying to do changes using DOM api to automate a process.

Answer (score 0):

> how to set the value to one of the available options

Try this example which picks the first option from the list

```js
document.querySelector('#genderListId').value = document.querySelector('#genderList').options[0].value;
```

```html
<input list="genderList" id="genderListId" autofocus='true' placeholder="Type .."/>
<datalist id="genderList">
    <option value="MALE"></option>
    <option value="FEMALE"></option>
 </datalist>
```